# Assign new ID taking into account previous changes

Tags: r, dataframe

Sorry I do not know how to properly title my question. It is easier to understand with an example.

**Sample data**
Consider the following example.

```
> l_ids=as.data.frame(cbind(a=c("strong","intense","intensity"),
id=c("1","2","3"),new_id=c("","1","2")),stringsAsFactors = FALSE)

               a id new_id
    1     strong  1       
    2    intense  2      1
    3   intensity 3      2
```

I would like to update the `id` of each word in `a` with a `new_id`, if it applies. Consider this as a synonym dictionary. As I iterate over `new_id`;

```
> for (i in 1:nrow(l_ids)){
+   if (nchar(l_ids$new_id[i])>0){
+     l_ids$id[i]=l_ids$new_id[i]
+   }
+ }
> l_ids
           a id new_id
1     strong  1       
2    intense  1      1
3  intensity  2      2
```

The problem is that I would like for `intensity` to also be given a `1`. Is there a way to do this without having to iterate multiple times?

**Update on background**

I have a document where I have a list of synonyms. These are synonyms only relevant to the field of application of the problem. Example:

```
> dictionary
     good       bad
1  strong   intense
2 intense intensity
3   light      soft
```

I am then given a list of words, each with a given `id`. My task is to check if any of those words is in the `bad` column of `dictionary` and, if so, update it with the `id` of the word to its left. As can be seen, `intensity` would need two steps to become `strong` (a `good` word in the dictionary). Is there a way to do so without having to do multiple iterations? (say, a `for` loop)

Comment: It's unclear to me what rule you want to follow to assign `new_id`. Should "intense" and "intensity" share a `new_id` because they share the same word root? If so, you will need to explore some [natural language processing packages](https://hub.packtpub.com/9-useful-r-packages-for-nlp-text-mining/).

Comment: i understand i should make the question more clear. Let me update it.

Comment: You want to make such a transition intensity -> intense -> strong - we have 2 levels here. How many levels the algorithm should support? In my opinion, it could be good approach to build final list of synonymes first - flatten it to one level i.e intense ->strong, intensity -> strong, soft -> light

Comment: If you are _also_ matching words in `strong` to words in `bad`, and don't have a depth limit, your logic could potentially hit an infinite loop. For example, add a 4th row to `dictionary`: `c("intensity", "strong")`